# Add elements to all empty keys of an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I use the following code to fill all empty keys in sub-arrays with ``` `` ```:

```
$array = array(
        'note' => array('test', 'test1'),
        'year' => array('2011','2010', '2012'),
        'type' => array('conference', 'journal', 'conference'),
    );

foreach ($array['type'] as $k => $v) {
  foreach($array as $element => $a) {
    $iterator = $array[$element];
    if(!isset($iterator[$k])){       
       $iterator[$key] = '';
    }
  }
}
```

print_r($array);

The problem is that it is not actually changing the elements in `$array` but in temporary variable `$iterator`.

I know that this is a simple question but I would like to find out the best and fastest solution.

Comment: Is it really intended to process the inner array in the outer loop, and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the $iterator variable, you can do just:

```
foreach ($array['type'] as $k => $v) {
  foreach($array as $element => $a) {
    if(!isset($array[$element][$k])){       
       $array[$element][$key] = '';
    }
  }
}
```

I would also recommending switching the  inner and outer loops, so it's more readable and more efficient.

```
foreach($array as $element => $a) {
       foreach ($array['type'] as $k => $v) {
        if(!isset($array[$element][$k])){       
           $array[$element][$key] = '';
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Actually, this is kinda weird, I'm not sure if I understood what you really want, would be nice if you could post how do you want your final array to be on your example.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have some typos. `$key` in the middle of the loops is never defined. 
`$a` should be the same value as `$iterator[$k]`, so no need to set it.

Try this.

```
$array = array(
        'note' => array('test', 'test1'),
        'year' => array('2011','2010', '2012'),
        'type' => array('conference', 'journal', 'conference'),
    );

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
  foreach($k as $element => $a) {
    if(!isset($a)){       
       $array[$element] = '';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what's the outer loop doing here?

Comment: @raina77ow, The array is nested. It goes 2 layers deep.

Comment: Sigh.. ok, I'd ask how `$k` and `$v` variables are used in your code then.

Comment: @salamis, just saw that the outer loop begins with `$array['type']` and not just `$array`. Are you sure this is exactly what you want?

Comment: @raina77ow, Nice catch, I changed the inner loop to use `$k` instead of `$array`. @Salamis, please retest this code.